# Where to find an adventure with a crashed spaceship

Tags: system-agnostic, published-adventures, science-fiction

I'm running a fantasy sandbox game and would like to include a crashed spaceship as an adventure location in the game.

Two of the player characters are humans with some scifi tech and they are survivors of the crash (via escape pods, I suppose), so the scifi material should be something in line with hard scifi, cyberpunk, Shadowrun or even Star Wars (and in particular not manned by flumphs, illithids or angels, etc.).

I can adapt a deck plan, if it includes stuff that lies in the rooms. In a fantasy setting most of that counts as serious loot. Any or no rules system is fine.

So, where can I find an adventure with a crashed spaceship or deck/floorplan of such with inventory included?

---

For clarity, I'm looking for:

- Adventure including a crashed spaceship, or floor/deck plans of space ship that include the inventory to be found there; list or random tables or whatever format for the inventory is fine.
- System does not matter. Any or no system works fine.
- The space ship should be such that it could have credibly included at least two humans (with cyberlimbs and other such technology) as crew and escape pods for them.
- Challenges in investigating the wreck, preferably included within the adventure itself. I can improvise this if necessary, but it would be nice to have them ready.
- An adventure available online, and available for free, would also be nice.

Comment: Is this your personal take on [Expedition to the Barrier Peaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_to_the_Barrier_Peaks)?

Answer (score 4):

Barrier Peaks, mentioned by okeefe already, sounds like a good place to start. It has a lot of the elements you're looking for. There's a followup adventure/article on the old Wizards site called "[Return Expedition to the Barrier Peaks](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20modern/article/20060505a)", and Dave Chalker wrote an article called "[Thingamagigs of the Barrier Peaks](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/dra/201204bazaar)" (D&D Insider sub. required) that has 4E stats for high tech weapons and armour for use in a fantasy setting.

Metamorphosis Alpha/Gamma World might also be a great place to find source material that may also fit what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Helpful as a start if you can't find anything else; there are lots of spaceship floorplans at [Paratime designs](http://paratime.ca/cartography/sf_spaceships.html)

Answer (score 2):

DriveThru has a couple of items that might be useful for you:

- [Crashed Spaceship battlemat](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/90466/The-Crashed-Spaceship---Battlemap)
- [Derelict alien starships](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/79304/Derelict-Alien-Starships?src=s_pi)

Comment: To fill out a blank or thin deckplan, *[Into the Future: Derelict Starships](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/64132/Into-the-Future%3A-Derelict-Starships)* would be very useful. It's a book of 100 bits of description that a GM can cherry-pick to give a derelict character and interesting hazards. I have another book in the line (for caverns) and the quality is hit-and-miss, but among 100 bits, the hits are frequent enough make quantity win over quality.

Answer (score 2):

There are deck plans for ships in almost every adventure ever published for Traveller rpg, plus there are a few in the rulebooks themselves, and a few books that primarily consist of nothing but deck plans for a pretty wide array of ships.  The GDW Traveller books are generally out-of-print now, but available to some degree from RPGnow.com, ebay, and similar sites, and Steve Jackson Games' GURPS Traveller is slightly more avaible, but the first Traveller volume is also out of print I believe.  There is at least one GURPS Traveller book, "Interstellar Wars," that is available in hardcopy (or at least it was last year).  It is also available electronically from e23 as are many other books of deckplans.  For example:  http://e23.sjgames.com/item.html?id=SJG37-0120

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a game of [Outlander](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0462465/)?  Needless to say, I approve of ripping Beowulf off.  In that case, the ship would be small or smashed so badly that it would not have much salvageable.  You may not want your PCs to have access to ordinance/power armours, medical facilities, and nanofabs!  Then again, it could make for an interesting game...

Or is it more of a [Pandorum](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1188729/) type of game?  In that case, the ship would take a whole new level of big.  Add horrible things in there and you have a "dungeon" that will slaughter poor little fantasy folks.  Still, this could be interesting.

On the loot note. Be careful what you give your players.  Any working technology can be horribly overpowered.  A power armour would make you the ruler of the medieval battle field: nothing could stop you...  Oh, and let's not forget all those diseases that the poor locals will start to get.  Remember the Conquista?...

Floor plans of space ships are hard to get but any Star War, Star Trek, and Traveller site out there will have many star ship floor plan with detailed descriptions of what's where.

Comment: I have not heard of either movie. As for balance, if the player characters get powerful, then I expect them to seek greater challenges, or just enjoy their power. I'm fine with either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are/know someone who has a copy of the original box set of TSR's Star Frontiers, then there is a pretty decent spaceship floorplan map in that.

Answer (score 0):

One of Wizards of the Coast's early adventures published for free online centered around a stranded monarch trying to find her way back to her ship: [The Vessel of Stars](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20001101a). It includes a small floorplan of the ship itself.

Comment: I know of it but find it ill-suited for my purposes, as it does not include enough detail and somehow feels wrong in this context. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the d20 system, you can easily find something to fill the necessary gaps without having to go too far.  Whether you are or aren't, I don't see why you can't just make a standard dungeon for the game's system and change the paint job so to speak.  Fireball trap? Or Napalm?  Lightning Bolt or Laser?  Pendulum trap or... Pendulum trap with more realistic reset?

Comment: Can you point out a specific adventure that would be well suited for such conversion, and that would contain suitable scifi loot or something easy to convert to suitable scifi loot?

Comment: What I was saying is that because of d20 modern, d20 Future, and magic in general, you can make technological items that mimic spell abilities on a 1:1 basis.  A "wand of lightning" can easily be turned into a laser pistol.  d20 modern has an "Ultramodern Firearms" guide if you need to equate weapons.  You could also probably look into Star Wars d20 as well.

Comment: I get that, but it does not help with questions such as "What useful loot can you find in the lounge room of a space ship?", for example. Even in D&D-medieval setting common scifi tools constitute serious loot. Your approach does not help with them.

Answer (score 0):

The random mutant future adventure generator at http://www.wizardawn.com/rpg/tool_uruins.php can create a crashed spaceship. The map does not look very much like a spaceship, though, so using some other resource for maps or deck plans is advised.

The description does include mundane room contents and monsters, many of which work as fantasy creatures of robots.